# Linear Actor Critic for continuing task and 1 continuous action => Any comment?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, actor-critic-methods, linear-regression

I wish to implement an Actor Critic agent using linear functions for a continuing task with one continuous action. Below the resulting pseudo-code I have reached by my own (the initialization part is removed).
$$
\begin{aligned}
& Observe \hspace{0.1cm} X \\
& Loop \hspace{0.1cm} until \hspace{0.1cm} STOP:\\
&  \hspace{0.5cm}\mu = \theta_{\mu }^{T} * X \\
&  \hspace{0.5cm}\sigma = ln\left (\theta_{\sigma }^{T} * X  \right ) \\
&  \hspace{0.5cm}a \leftarrow N(\mu , \sigma ) \\ 
&  \hspace{0.5cm}Take \hspace{0.1cm}action\hspace{0.1cm} a, \hspace{0.1cm}observe\hspace{0.1cm} X' \\
&  \hspace{0.5cm}\delta \leftarrow R - \overline{R} + w^{T} * X' - w^{T} * X \\
&  \hspace{0.5cm}\overline{R} \leftarrow \overline{R} + \alpha _{\overline{R}} * \delta \\
&  \hspace{0.5cm}w \leftarrow w + \alpha_{w} * \delta * (R-\overline{R}+w^{T}*X'-w^{T}*X)*X \\
&  \hspace{0.5cm}\theta_{\mu} \leftarrow \theta _{\mu}  + \alpha_{\mu}*\delta * \frac{a-\mu}{\sigma^{2}}*X \\
&  \hspace{0.5cm}\theta_{\sigma} \leftarrow \theta _{\sigma}  + \alpha_{\sigma}*\delta * \left (  \frac{\left ( a-\mu \right )^{2} }{\sigma^{2}}- 1 \right )*X\\
&  \hspace{0.5cm}X \leftarrow X'
\end{aligned}
$$
My mathematics level is not high. I would be grateful if somebody could check. My questions: 
 <s>1) Can somebody help me to complete the update of theta_mu and theta_sigma (lines with question marks) ?</s> 
I finally found something I missed in Sutton & Barto book, so I could complete the updates and remove question 1.
2) Does somebody see any mistake or have any remark ? 
Many thanks for the attention.